# Javafx WebView and Youtube videos

Tags: youtube, javafx, youtube-iframe-api

I'm building simple web browser using JavaFX but I found that there are some problems with playing youtube videos in it.
To reproduce the problem just run this simple code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        WebView root = new WebView();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        root.getEngine().load("http://youtube.com");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

When I try to play youtube video I see that it sometimes work but more often it shows the message "An error occurred, please try again later" (with the same movie).
As far as I know JavaFX uses Webkit so there should not be big differences between playing youtube (html5) videos in Chrome/Firefox or using WebView. I tried JRE 1.8.0, 1.8.20 and two different notebooks and it didn't help.

When video somehow start working there is error message:

```
Outstanding resource locks detected:
D3D Vram Pool: 15 529 382 used (5,8%), 15 529 382 managed (5,8%), 268 435 456 total
41 total resources being managed
average resource age is 12.8 frames
0 resources at maximum supported age (0,000000)
10 resources marked permanent (24,400000)
3 resources have had mismatched locks (7,300000)
3 resources locked (7,300000)
15 resources contain interesting data (36,600000)
0 resources disappeared (0,000000)
```

So I think these two problems can be connected with memory leaks in webview. Am I right or do You think there is maybe other solution to solve this problem?

Comment: May be you are using different URL to view the same video. [Check this out](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/35817/youtube-why-are-some-videos-html5-and-some-flash-and-how-do-i-force-html5)

Comment: It doesn't matter if I use "youtube.com" as it is in provided example or if I use iframe with embedded player on other website. There is always problem that video does not start or eclipse shows problem with memory.
I sent the code to my friend and he has exactly the same result, so there is a problem with WebView, not with youtube. I tried to use DJ Project but since JavaFx have poor support for Swing components it does not work too.